# Как посчитать сколько остановок нужно проехать?

Tags: javascript

Очень нужна помощь в JavaScript. Задание для новичков, но совсем не удаётся решить ее.

Дано три линии ветки метро и нужно посчитать расстояние между станциями. Все три линии пересекаются только на одной станции “Park Street”. Скажем, если я сяду на одной станции метро, а выйду на другой, то сколько остановок я проеду?

Ниже прилагается скелет кода. Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

```js
const subwayLines = {
  Red: [
    'South Station',
    'Park Street',
    'Kendall',
    'Central',
    'Harvard',
    'Porter',
    'Davis',
    'Alewife'
  ],
  Green: [
    'Government Center',
    'Park Street',
    'Boylston',
    'Arlington',
    'Copley',
    'Hynes',
    'Kenmore'
  ],
  Orange: [
    'North Station',
    'Haymarket',
    'Park Street',
    'State',
    'Downtown Crossing',
    'Chinatown',
    'Back Bay',
    'Forest Hills'
  ]
}


const stopNumber = function (stop, line) {
 for (let i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    if (line[i] === stop) {
       return i
     }
   }

  return 0
 }

 const stopsOnOneLine = function (line, start, end) {
   const stops =
     stopNumber(start, subwayLines[line]) -
     stopNumber(end, subwayLines[line])

   return stops < 0 ? -stops : stops
 }

 const stopsBetweenStations = (startLine, startStation, endLine, endStation) => {
   let stops = 0
   if (startLine === endLine) {
    stops = stopsOnOneLine(startLine, startStation, endStation)
   } else {
     stops = stopsOnOneLine(startLine, startStation, 'Park Street') +
       stopsOnOneLine(endLine, endStation, 'Park Street')
   }
```

Comment: Эта задача решается алгоритмом Дейсктры по поиску кратчайшего пути.

Comment: @sneas зачем? Тут самый простой граф, можно просто вычитать индексы станции с разных веток и сложить их потом

Comment: @ThisMan вы имеете ввиду, проставить веса для каждой из станций относительно ParkStreet, и потом найти нужные станции и сложить веса? Клёвая идея :)

Comment: @ThisMan или можно как-то без весов проделать? На одних индексах не могу понять как...

Comment: Если обе станции на одной ветке - то все просто, не так ли (кол-во остановок = модуль разницы между индексами станций в массиве для данной ветки). Если станции на разных ветках, то действуем как предложил @ThisMan: считаем остановки от станции `А` до `Park Street` и прибавляем остановки от `Park Street` до станции `Б` (т.е по сути, 2 раза применить логику из 1го случая, которую можно вынести в отдельную функцию). В более общем случае задача решалась бы через поиск в ширину на графе. Но здесь слишком простое условие ,чтобы использовать графы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const subwayLines = {
  Red:    ['South Station','Park Street','Kendall','Central','Harvard','Porter','Davis','Alewife'],
  Green:  ['Government Center','Park Street','Boylston','Arlington','Copley','Hynes','Kenmore'],
  Orange: ['North Station','Haymarket','Park Street','State','Downtown Crossing','Chinatown','Back Bay','Forest Hills']
}

function stationIndex(line, station) {
  for (var i = 0; i < subwayLines[line].length; i++) {
    if (subwayLines[line][i] == station)
      return i;
  }
}

const stopsBetweenStations = (startLine, startStation, endLine, endStation) => {
  if (startLine == endLine) {
    return Math.abs(stationIndex(startLine, startStation) - stationIndex(endLine, endStation));
  } else {
    var start = Math.abs(stationIndex(startLine, startStation) - stationIndex(startLine, 'Park Street'));
    var end = Math.abs(stationIndex(endLine, endStation) - stationIndex(endLine, 'Park Street'));
    return start + end;
  }
}

console.log(stopsBetweenStations('Green', 'Hynes', 'Orange', 'North Station'));
console.log(stopsBetweenStations('Red', 'Alewife', 'Red', 'Central'));
console.log(stopsBetweenStations('Red', 'Central', 'Red', 'Alewife'));
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ВАМ!!!!!!

Comment: @Даша На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае задача становится довольно простой. Раз все станции пересекаются только в одной точке, то что бы посчитать кол-во станций, которые будут между двумя точками, достаточной сложить разницу между первой точкой и станцией пересечения и второй точкой и станцией пересечения. Строить графы и искать пути нужно в случае, если бы схема была бы сложнее)

```js
const subwayLines = {
  Red: [
    'South Station',
    'Park Street',
    'Kendall',
    'Central',
    'Harvard',
    'Porter',
    'Davis',
    'Alewife'
  ],
  Green: [
    'Government Center',
    'Park Street',
    'Boylston',
    'Arlington',
    'Copley',
    'Hynes',
    'Kenmore'
  ],
  Orange: [
    'North Station',
    'Haymarket',
    'Park Street',
    'State',
    'Downtown Crossing',
    'Chinatown',
    'Back Bay',
    'Forest Hills'
  ]
}

const CROSSROAD = 'Park Street';

const getStationIndex = (line, station) =>
  line.findIndex(s => s === station);

const hasLineStation = (line, station) =>
  getStationIndex(line, station) !== -1;

const getStationsCountInPath =
  (startLine, startStation, endLine, endStation) => {
    if (!hasLineStation(startLine, startStation) ||
        !hasLineStation(endLine, endStation)) {
      throw new Error('Wrong subway sheme');    
    }
    return (
      Math.abs(getStationIndex(startLine, startStation) - getStationIndex(startLine, CROSSROAD)) +
      Math.abs(getStationIndex(endLine, endStation) - getStationIndex(endLine, CROSSROAD)) + 1
    );
  };

console.log('from Arlington to Downtown Crossing', getStationsCountInPath(
  subwayLines.Green,
  'Arlington',
  subwayLines.Orange,
  'Downtown Crossing'
));

console.log('from North Station to Downtown Crossing', getStationsCountInPath(
  subwayLines.Orange,
  'North Station',
  subwayLines.Orange,
  'Downtown Crossing'
));

console.log('from Alewife to Forest Hills', getStationsCountInPath(
  subwayLines.Red,
  'Alewife',
  subwayLines.Orange,
  'Forest Hills'
));
```

P.S. 
*Мой вариант включает первую и последнюю станцию. Так что если это не нужно, просто вычитайте 2)*

Comment: я не понял второй тест,  ведь на   `subwayLines.Green` нет ни `'North Station'` ни  `'Downtown Crossing'`

Comment: `getStationsCountInPath(
  subwayLines.Green,
  'Kenmore',
  subwayLines.Green,
  'Copley'
)` и вот такой тест дает не правильный результат

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, это я тут опечатался. Не делал просто проверку на то, что станция есть на линии. Поэтому все равно можно получить результат)